# class member function won't return

Tags: c++, class, freeze, class-members

I have following code:

```
void module_books::show_item(int n, TABLE<BOOK> b) {
  cout<<"Title:         "<<b[n]->title<<"\n";
  cout<<"Author:        "<<b[n]->author<<"\n";
  cout<<"Issue:         "<<"no. "<<b[n]->issueno<<". "<<b[n]->city<<", "<<b[n]->publisher<<", "<<b[n]->year<<"\n";
  cout<<"ISBN:          "<<b[n]->isbn<<"\n";
  cout<<"Pages count:   "<<b[n]->pages<<"\n";
  cout<<"Information:   Loan count: "<<b[n]->outcount<<". ";
  if(b[n]->damaged) cout<<"DAMAGED ";
  if(b[n]->out) cout<<"LOANED";
  cout<<"\n\n";
}

int module_books::add_item(TABLE<BOOK> &b) {

  int _year, _issueno, _pages;
  bool _damaged=false;
  string _title, _author, _isbn, _publisher, _city, stmp;

  cout<<"You're adding new book to the list.\nFill in the following fields:\n\n";
  cout<<"Title:               "; getline(cin,_title);
  cout<<"Author:              "; getline(cin,_author);
  cout<<"Issue no:            "; cin>>_issueno; cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), L'\n');
  cout<<"Issued in (city):    "; getline(cin,_city);
  cout<<"Issuer:              "; getline(cin,_publisher);
  cout<<"Issued in (year):    "; cin>>_year; cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), L'\n');
  cout<<"ISBN:                "; getline(cin,_isbn);
  cout<<"Pages count:         "; cin>>_pages;
  cout<<"Is damaged? (y/n):   "; cin>>stmp; cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), L'\n');
  if(stmp=="y" || stmp=="yes" || stmp=="Y" || stmp=="Yes" || stmp=="YES") _damaged=true;

  int n=b.size();

  b.push_back(BOOK(_title,_author,_publisher,_city,_isbn,_year,_issueno,_pages,_damaged));

  cout<<"\nThe book has been added:\n\n";
  show_item(n,b);
  cout<<"\nreturning\n";
  return n;
}
```

BOOK is just a struct with some member variables. TABLE is a struct template, that works like STL vector (I'm just not allowed to use vector, so had to write my own template, at the moment it's using static array `T ar[100]`).

The problem is that I get the message that the book has been added and show_item function prints all the data, but I get no "returning" message.

I tried setting breakpoints so the `show_table` function reaches the ending `}`, but the program never gets to the "returning" message.

What might be wrong with this code? I'm using 32-bit QTCreator with MinGW. My OS is 64-bit Win8.1 if that would help...

Comment: http://sscce.org

Comment: You have likely a messed up copy constructor - a quick fix: `void module_books::show_item(int n, const TABLE<BOOK>& b)`

Comment: @burtek Please fix your invalid code, too